# Como inverter linhas e colunas em uma tabela HTML preenchida pelo retorno de uma query?

Tags: php, html, mysql, table, tabela-html

Preciso preencher uma tabela na minha pagina HTML com dados retornados de uma query do banco.

O problema é que a tag TABLE preenche linha por linha, da esquerda para a direita.

No layout que preciso utilizar, preciso que cada linha do array retornado preencha uma coluna.

Detalhe, preciso utilizar a tag TABLE porque preciso imprimir isso em excel depois.

```
    echo "<table>";
         while ($temp = $registros-> fetch_assoc()){
              echo "<tr>";
                   foreach ($temp as $mes){
                       echo "<th>".$mes."</th>";
                   }
              echo "</tr>";           
        }    
   echo "</table>";
```

Retorno da query:
Array ( [Mes] => Janeiro  [col1] => 30 [col2] => 25)
Array ( [Mes] => Fevereiro [col1] => 30 [col2] => 25)
Array ( [Mes] => Março [col1] => 30 [col2] => 25)

Resultado: [image: resultado do codigo acima]

Desejado:
[image: Como eu preciso que fique]

Answer (score 0):

Esse requisito seria o pivot na sua query, uma possibilidade é vc alterar a query que existe e utilizar o UNION ALL, sendo uma query para cada coluna que vc deseja que apareça na sua tabela, assim vc não alteraria seu código no front-end

Answer (score 0):

Depois de dias pensando na melhor forma, e embasado na resposta do amigo acima, cheguei a conclusão que a forma menos trabalhosa é criar novos arrays (um para cada linha da minha tabela), e depois preencher a TABLE com os novos arrays.

Simples, porém difícil de pensar quando se esta no meio de um projeto full stack.